# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS crashing when second monitor is connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, amdgpu

I'm having some trouble with using my 2 monitors on Ubuntu. Whenever I connect a second one, it shows the background, but if I move my mouse over to it, my entire system hangs. I can't do anything to fix it except to cut the power. I have a ATI Radeon HD 4770 (512MB VRAM) with a Xeon W3565 and 8GB of RAM. I tried to install Ubuntu MATE and it worked really unstable. My PC restarts itself 3 times before it works. However on normal Ubuntu, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That CPU is power hungry so you should have a recommend power supply to cover the extra wattage draw from the video card. 
Try installing the latest Ubuntu 18.04 kernel or just install use

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Shutdown and start computer with 2nd monitor already plugged in. 
Swap video cables to make sure it isn't a bad cable. 
Verify that your are using the native resolution for the monitor or lower the resolution manually is the Display settings.

If that still doesn't work then grab the proprietary driver from AMD for your card.

https://www2.ati.com/drivers/legacy/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.zip